# How to test if proxy is working correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, proxy, script

I am trying to test if proxy is working correctly using this script. Problem is that it no matter what ends by    echo "Proxy is working" . Any ideas please ?

```
export http_proxy='http://proxy.test.cz:1234/'

OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/$$.txt
    wget -nv --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test google.com > ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1

grep -q '<H1>You cant use internet</H1>' ${OUTPUT_FILE}
if [ "$?" -eq '0' ]
then
    echo "Proxy isnt working. " | mail -s "Proxy isnt working" -r "No-reply<no-reply@mail.cz>" test@mail.cz
else
    echo "Proxy is working"
fi

rm -f /tmp/$$.txt
```

Comment: `if [ $?...]` is a shell antipattern; just test the command directly instead.  And no need for `$OUTPUT_FILE`; just use a pipe: `if wget ... | grep ....; then`.  Perhaps your test is wrong, e.g. by misspelling *can't* or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it this way :

```
export http_proxy='http://proxy.test.cz:1234/'
URL='www.google.com'

wget -q --proxy-user=test --proxy-password=test --spider $URL
if [ $? = 1 ]
then
    STATUS= echo "Proxy isn't working"

else
  STATUS="Proxy is working."
fi
echo $STATUS
```

Answer (score 2):

Although somewhat old question, but it may be still have some value to provide another answer. So here is mine:

```
set_proxies() {
    export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:998
    export HTTP_PROXY=${http_proxy}
    export https_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:999
    export HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}
    export ftp_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:998
    export FTP_PROXY=${ftp_proxy}
    export socks_proxy=socks://proxy.example.com:9999
    export SOCKS_PROXY=${socks_proxy}
    export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,.docker.io,192.168.9.100
    export NO_PROXY=${no_proxy}        
    export ALL_PROXY_NO_FALLBACK=1
    export all_proxy=socks5://proxy.example.com:9999   
}

URL='www.google.com'

curl -s -m 2 $URL > /dev/null

if [ $? == 0 ] then
    STATUS="No Corporate Proxy"
else
    set_proxies
    STATUS="Behind Corporate proxy"
fi
echo $STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the quotes around $? in the if check:

```
if [ "$?" -eq '0' ]
```

When the grep didn't find the string you were looking for, the return code was 1. So this if check equates to:

```
if [ "1" -eq '0' ]
```

which is always false, hence you get "Proxy is working".

Use

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

instead.